# Mass and center of gravity $G$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to find the limits while calculating the mass and center of gravity for the lamina $\rho(x,y)=y$ bounded by $D=\{y=\sin x, y=0, x=\pi\}$,

$$M=\iint_D\rho(x,y)\, dA$$

How to find the limits for both integral? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Draw the region.

Presumably you require $0\leq x\leq\pi$, so $x$ varies between $0$ and $\pi$.

For any fixed $x$ in this interval, $y$ varies between $0$ and $\sin x$.

Since $\rho\;dA=y\;dy \;dx$, you must compute
$$\int_{x=0}^{x=\pi}\int_{y=0}^{y=\sin x}y\; dy \;dx
$$

Comment: Thanks a million. This helped. I shall take it forward!

Comment: @Aruha Very nice comment. :-)